# How do I prevent resolvconf to add %eth0 to an address in resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, dhcp

My raspberry runs the follwing relevant services:

- isc-dhcp-server
- bind9
- radvd

The message I get from isc-dhcp-server is this:

```
Unable to set resolver from resolv.conf; startup continuing but DDNS support may be affected
```

The issue in resolv.conf is this line:

```
nameserver fe80::1%eth0
```

If I remove the `%eth0` part, which tells the raspberry on which interface the address is found, everything works as expected. But alas, it is added back when the file is regenerated.

I tried to reconfigure the package, by using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf`, but I got the message that the package is not installed.

How do I prevent resolvconf to add %eth0 to the specified address in resolv.conf? It is unneeded, the raspberry is the DNS of the network and has a forwarding address specified.

My `dhcpcd.conf`:

```
 interface eth0
 static ip_address=10.10.10.252/24
 static ip6_address=fc00::1/64
 static routers=10.10.10.254
 static domain_name_servers=10.10.10.252 fc00::1
```